# Why has RealVNC's VNC Viewer stopped connecting to my Mac fullscreen?

Tags: mac, resolution, vnc, vnc-viewer

I've been using VNC Viewer to connect to my Mac Mini for some time now. I got things set up so that the viewer would dictate the resolution, so I could use the full resolution of my monitor (which is 1920x1080). However, when I was using it the other day I think I accidentally hit some kind of key combination and now when I connect, the display does not occupy my full screen.

To be clear, it wasn't a scaled display: it was natively 1920x1080. But now my Mac insists on displaying at what looks to be 1280x1024. My Mac's display settings don't seem to help:

[image]

I've tried playing around with VNC Viewer's settings too with no success:

[image]

Any idea how I can get back to connecting with 1920x1080 resolution?

Comment: If you plug your monitor in does it work? The screen shot of your Mac Mini's display properties shows it is headless (without a monitor).